# \psmatrix doesn't work with mnode in beamer class

Tags: beamer, psmatrix

I would like to draw a few simple graphs in my `beamer` presentation. I'm using following imports:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{rose}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
```

I would like first just draw a single node in a circle. Following code works:

```
$
\psmatrix
v\\
\endpsmatrix
$
```

But as soon as I try to add the option mnode, the build breaks:

```
$
\psmatrix[mnode=circle]
v\\
\endpsmatrix
$
```

Do you have any idea what goes wrong here? The error message I get regards to a line after the usage of `psmatrix` and doesn't provide any hint to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've just found out, that pstricks does not work with pdftex nor with any other driver that produces anything but PostScript code. (http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf)

So I'll be using tikz for my graphics. Following code sample does exactly, what I wish:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, circle]{v};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `pstricks` *can* work with pdflatex: just load `auto-pst-pdf` and add the `-shell-escape` switch to the compiler command.

Answer (score 2):

It does work with  `auto-pst-pdf` and adding the `-shell-escape`switch to the command line of pdflatex. You also have to use the `psmatrix environment`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{rose}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-tree}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

$ \begin{psmatrix}[mnode=circle]
v\\
\end{psmatrix} $

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Bernard. I've already finished my slides with tikz-package, but it's good to know for the next time!